# Can't get rid of non-unicode characters in numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, unicode

I have a table:
`vals = table.iloc[sum(which(pa_i),[1]),1:]`
content:

```
Out[249]: 
                      1         2       3
2  NA [1] (16.0 to N/A)  12.0 [2]  NA [1]
```

When I write `vals.values` I get:
vals

```
Out[250]: array([['NA\xa0[1] (16.0\xa0to\xa0N/A)', '12.0\xa0[2]', 'NA\xa0[1]']], dtype=object)
```

I simply want to get this table to an array or list but earlier want to replace `\xa0` values. When I apply:
`v = print(map(lambda s: s.replace('\xa0' , ' '), vals))` I don't know how to read this object or when
`np.char.replace(vals[0],'\xa0' , ' ')` I get error "TypeError: string operation on non-string array".

What is the easiest way to convert the content to array or to replace unwanted chars??

**EDIT**

I've got a solution: `v = vals.astype('str')` and `v = np.char.replace(v,'\xa0' , ' ')`.

```
Out[306]: array([['NA [1] (16.0 to N/A)', '12.0 [2]', 'NA [1]']], dtype='<U20')
```

But I'm not fully satisfied of this answer. I need something to work directly on `vals` variable - for example by doing this:
`a = vals[1:].toarray(?)`
expected result:

```
a
Out[318]: ['(16.0 to N/A)', '12.0 [2]', 'NA [1]]']
```

Comment: Why do you want to get rid of those `'\xa0'` chars? That's the non-break space char; I assume they're there so that those strings (column headings) don't get split if line-wrapping gets applied to them.

Comment: I just want to get pure numbers from the row. This row is already extracted from pandas data frame by some previous operations.

Answer (score 0):

Well, its because it contains `int` elements and not `str`

Do this:

```
table.values = [str(v) for v in table.values]
```

Comment: I've got a solution: `v = vals.astype('str')` and `v = np.char.replace(v,'\xa0' , ' ')`. Out[306]: 
array([['NA [1] (16.0 to N/A)', '12.0 [2]', 'NA [1]']], 
      dtype='<U20')

Answer (score 0):

I have found the best way:

```
vals
Out[357]: 
                      1         2       3
2  NA [1] (16.0 to N/A)  12.0 [2]  NA [1]
```

`a = vals.values.tolist()`

```
a
Out[358]: [['NA\xa0[1] (16.0\xa0to\xa0N/A)', '12.0\xa0[2]', 'NA\xa0[1]']]
```

`a1 = [w.replace('\xa0', ' ') for w in a[0]]`

```
a1
Out[359]: ['NA [1] (16.0 to N/A)', '12.0 [2]', 'NA [1]']
```

Pffff. Maybe not the prettiest in terms of coding habits but what can we do.